# GCE Zones FAQ Project Data at rest

Tags: google-compute-engine

Reading the FAQ about compute engine and regions and zones it mentions they are to provide low latency connectivity from those regions but that "at this time selection of data center will make no guarantee that project data at rest is kept only in that region."

Does that mean portions (blocks) of data on persistent disks not currently in use in a given compute instance''s ram or CPU could be located outside the region or is it referring to units of data as individual disk or entire snapshots not currently attached to a running instance?

How does that affect data protection issues where location of data within EU is required for compliance

Answer (score 1):

According to [the comments from Google on my blog post about GCE](http://gigaom.com/2014/03/02/5-things-you-probably-dont-know-about-google-cloud/), this actually means that the "project" data isn't guaranteed to be in the region which is data like the name of the project, billing info, lists of instances, etc. Your actual data on persistent disks, instances, MySQL, etc will be stored in the region you choose.

Comment: Not as scarly as 1st thought so